# How to add new setter programatically in existing ItemContainerStyle in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have item container style for list view like below :

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-1"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=EventType}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Now I need to add new setter for context menu programatically based on item data. How can I do it ?

Please guide me.....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented logic to add setter dynamically in existing style like below :

```
listview1.ItemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.ContextMenuProperty,GetItemContextMenu(txtName.Text)));
```

But it gives me following error : 
"After a 'SetterBaseCollection' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified."

I think it is not possible to add new setter in sealed style. So I have got another temporary solution like assign context menu to whole listview rather than it's item on preview mouse right click event. So context menu will be same for all items then managed in coding based on data of selected item.

Answer (score 9):

I have to display Images dynamically and show/hide depends on state of checkboxes using Style and DataTrigger.

```
<Image Source="/WpfApplication;component/Imgs/img1_1.png">
<Image.Style>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Image.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=isDisplayingImgSet1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Image.Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

After spec modification i have to create checkboxes dynamically, then to set Style.
At beginning, I have the same error message.

```
Image img = new Image();
//..
img.Style.Setters.Add(setter);
img.Style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
//..After a 'SetterBaseCollection' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified.
```

The solution is to create a style object and Affect it to Image.Style

```
//Visibility
DataTrigger trigger = new DataTrigger();
trigger.Binding = new Binding
{
     ElementName = "isDisplayingImgSet"+NumSet,
     Path = new PropertyPath(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty)
};
trigger.Value = "True";
trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(ContentControl.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Visible));

Setter setter = new Setter(ContentControl.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed);
Style style = new Style(typeof(Image));
style.Setters.Add(setter);
style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
img.Style = style;
```

Hope that helping you

PS : It's my first post

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-1"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                  <ContextMenu/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=EventType}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu/>
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I need to add context menu and it's event handlers dynamically based on binded data of item, not static please.

Comment: could you provide more details? do you use MVVM? to which collection is list box bound?

Comment: I need to make context menu dynamically on mouse right click or item selection changed events cause I need to add menu items based on item selected in list view for example : if my col1 = 1 then there will be 2 menu items, if col1 = 2 then there will be 3 menu items and so on. Also this conditions will be not only for one column it is based on data of 2 or 3 columns. So I can't make static context menus for each data trigger as you created in your code. So I need to make it dynamic on right click or selection changed events. I hope this will give you more idea about my requirements.....

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new Style() and "re-add" the the setters, you can get around this issue if you are using Telerik.

```
    private static void AddColumnSetter(GridViewColumn gridColumn, SetterBase setter)
    {
        var setters = new SetterBaseCollection();

        if (gridColumn.CellStyle != null)
        {
            foreach (SetterBase setterBase in gridColumn.CellStyle.Setters)
            {
                setters.Add(setterBase);
            }
        }

        setters.Add(setter);
        gridColumn.CellStyle = new Style();

        foreach (var setr in setters)
        {
            gridColumn.CellStyle.Setters.Add(setr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `'System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn'` does not contain a definition for `'CellStyle'`

Comment: I should have mentioned that the type is Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn.