# How to unset an element value in code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, border, styling

I have an xaml `border` element that has a `isMouseOver` effect. It basically changes the opacity of the background on the `border` from `0` to `0.2` so that you can visibly see that you're hovering over the border. Here's the `border`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" x:Key="hoverOver">
    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="LightGray"/>
    <Setter Property="Border.Opacity" Value="0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Border.Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Border x:Name="border1" Height="50" Width="350" Style="{StaticResource hoverOver}"/>
```

**Note:** Make sure you see that the opacity of the border is set in the style and not in the element itself. This is important.

In my code, the user "selects" the border (e.g. I set a permanent value for the opacity of the element by calling `border1.opacity = 0.2`). Now that an opacity value is set in the element, the styling no longer works even if I set `border1.opacity = 0`.

*You can try this for yourself by setting the opacity for the border. When you hover over it, it won't do anything because you set the opacity in the element instead of the style. As long as you set the value in the element the style does nothing to change it.*

How can I "unset" the value and remove the opacity value from the `border` allowing the style to effect the opacity again?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, once you set the property value, it overrides all styles and there's no way to "unset" it.  I've even tried setting the value back to Double.NaN to no avail.

Having said that, instead of setting the value directly as you're doing, you can probably achieve what you want by replacing the style with a new one that has the value that you want.  Something like this top answer: [How to add new setter programatically in existing ItemContainerStyle in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120781/how-to-add-new-setter-programatically-in-existing-itemcontainerstyle-in-wpf)

By replacing the style entirely, you are in full control of its setter value.  Then, when you want to "Unset" it, you just set the border's style back to your "hoverOver" resource.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the value of the dependency property instead of setting it to `0`:

```
border1.ClearValue(UIElement.OpacityProperty);
```